# Which crytographic libraries to use for Elliptic Curve Cryptography and Bilinear Pairing?

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation

I'm currently trying to implement a solution for Vehicular ad hoc networks based on cryptography. I've chosen to use python to implement the solution, but I don't know which libraries I have to use to implement the cryptographic functions (methods and modules). I've searched about it, but I didn't find good ones: most of the libraries I've found were about implementing Cipher algorithms and hash functions. I need libraries for Elliptic curve cryptography and Bilinear pairing. Please, suggest to me good libraries that have good methods.

PS: I'm using Python3.8 and Ubuntu OS, and these are the solutions that I'm working on [https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~misra/papers/T-ITS-2011.pdf](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/%7Emisra/papers/T-ITS-2011.pdf) and https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/10/1687/htm

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/ethereum/py_ecc ? It has an implementation of BN curve, which is a pairing friendly curve.

Comment: Thank u i will check it out

Comment: Caveat: The paper in the question's second link is remarkable in that it fails to determine the order of the elliptic curve it uses, doesn't state the signature system it applies, and cites 36 references on the same subject, many similarly defective or vacuous. I [asked why on Academia-se](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/160509).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pbc library](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) (The Pairing-Based Cryptography Library).